# Map SQL (not JPQL) to a collection of simple Java objects?

Tags: java, sql, orm, pojo

I can't believe I'm asking this, but...

Is there any way, in Java, to execute a SQL statement (not JPQL) and map the results to a `List` of Plain Old Java Objects?

I want to be able to create small lightweight POJO objects and then have them populated by raw SQL queries. I'm expressly **NOT** looking to create complex objects: just primitives, with no relationships.

Everything seems to be centered around JPA/JPQL, but the problem with that is that I do not want to bind my objects to a specific table.

I feel like I'm either:

- (a) on crazy pills, or
- (b) missing something fundamental

Answer (score 3):

A lightweight mapper is not available as part of the JDK itself. You could either roll-your-own simple mapper using Java's standard [JDBC API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) (in fact JPA implementations build on top of that) or you could have a look at external libraries that provide simple SQL-to-Object mappers. I know [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/) (formerly known as iBatis).

A) No, I think you're not on crazy pills and B) is it possible that you just missed JDBC?

Answer (score 2):

[Sormula](http://www.sormula.org) may be able to do what you want. You would need to extend [Table](http://www.sormula.org/javadoc/org/sormula/Table.html) and override getTableName() and/or getQualifiedTableName() to supply the desired table name since sormula normally associates one POJO to one table. See [example 2a](http://www.sormula.org/example2b/) and [example 3a](http://www.sormula.org/example3a/).

Comment: Since version 1.2, you no longer need inheritance to accomplish this. Simply use Table setTableName method.

Answer (score 0):

[jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) has a couple of Record -> POJO mapping capabilities that will probably do the job for you (although jOOQ can do much more). Here's an example:

```
// A "mutable" POJO class
public class MyBook1 {
  public int id;
  public String title;
}

// The various "into()" methods allow for fetching records into your POJOs:
List<MyBook1> myBooks = create.select().from(BOOK).fetchInto(MyBook1.class);
```

Taken from the manual here:
http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos/

The mapping algorithm is described in the Javadoc:
http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html

While the above example makes use of jOOQ's DSL API, you can do with plain SQL as well:

```
List<MyBook1> myBooks = create.resultQuery("SELECT * FROM BOOK")
                              .fetchInto(MyBook1.class);
```

You can even operate on a JDBC ResultSet, using jOOQ only for mapping:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
List<MyBook1> myBooks = create.fetch(rs).into(MyBook1.class);
```