# Java ORM and querying POJO's in memory or using other API's

Tags: java, database, orm

I want to or need to (without the use of other databases) setup Entities(database tables) in memory that have relationships, like one-to-many or many-to-many etc.

I saw something related here on this forum:
[Map SQL (not JPQL) to a collection of simple Java objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763242/map-sql-not-jpql-to-a-collection-of-simple-java-objects)

I need to query these Entities that have relationships and get the resultsets from this,
in order to push the resulting data into an Access database, I am using Jackcess and its not a JDBC driver.
So far I have looked at [MetaModel](http://metamodel.eobjects.org/) and [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org).
Is there anything else out there. I have a little bit of exposure to ORM's, do they query the in-memory collections or only just pass the sql query to the database.

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you're looking for something like .NET's [LINQ-to-Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx) in the Java ecosystem. There's nothing as sophisticated as LINQ-to-Objects, but there are a couple of ways to "query" collections in Java as well. You might be interested in any of these libraries:

- Quaere: http://quaere.codehaus.org
- Coolection: https://github.com/wagnerandrade/coollection
- Lambdaj: https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj
- JXPath: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath
- JoSQL: http://josql.sourceforge.net

All of the above projects are open source and may not be so actively maintained anymore, as Java 8 will introduce a [much better collections API](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/collections-overview.html) along with language-supported lambda expressions, which renders these [non-SQL focused LINQesque Java APIs](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/07/01/linq-and-java/) obsolete.

Note, you were asking specifically about [MetaModel](http://metamodel.eobjects.org/) and [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org). These provide you with a querying API for querying databases. I think that will not help you much for your use-cases.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate will query the object cache, but only if you query using Criteria or HQL.  If you query straight SQL, it'll get run directly against the database.

Your problem description sounds like it's more than Jackcess can handle natively, but what if at program startup you read the full Access DB into an in-memory database (one that has a JDBC driver), run Hibernate queries against that in-memory database, and then at program exit just flush all Hibernate changes to the in-memory database and then write the in-memory database's contents into the Access database?  You get all the complicated querying capability of Hibernate, and all you have to do is write Jackcess-to-JDBC code to load the Access DB into an equivalent schema in the in-memory database and then the inverse code to copy it back, which is way easier than writing the full JDBC driver for Jackcess.

Comment: Hi there, Yes I can use an in memory database, my favorite is the java H2 database. Note that I have stated that I CANNOT use a database with JDBC driver. The MS Access database does not exist at first and will be created then from external datasources tables will be created and those tables populated. I have got this far. With Jackcess it CANNOT QUERY tables that have relationships. So I need to do this in-memory. So my question is which other API's out there can I used to do this. So I pose this problem with these constraints of not using an in-memory database.

Comment: I believe my suggestion fits within your constraints (though your question didn't explain that your original data doesn't already reside in the Access database, and you should probably clarify that).  It sounds like you thought I was suggesting querying the Access DB via Jackcess, but that's not what I suggested.  I'm suggesting you load the data into something like H2 that supports JDBC and Hibernate, do your Hibernate querying against that, and then use Jackcess (without using JDBC) to copy the relevant information from your in-memory DB to Access.

Comment: Hi, so Tim you are saying that with Hibernate you can query the objects in memory using its HQL query language. But in using an ORM like Hibernate does it not require a JDBC driver for a particular database, because I see that when you need put these things into the persistence.xml or properties files. So correct me if i am wrong in assuming that with Hibernate you always need to specify some JDBC driver and some database. Otherwise if you don't include these specifications I fear that ORM base app either wont compile or wont run.

Comment: Hi Tim, Yes I did understand what you were saying. Also if I were going to use H2 in memory I would avoid using an ORM and just query the H2 database with SQL instead. So like I mentioned I am looking for a solution that does not use another database or using JDBC driver.

Comment: What you're asking for, then, is an ORM that only maps the objects to conceptual tables (not actually physically implemented in any data store, just "understood" by the ORM) that will allow you to do SQL queries against that conceptual tablespace and will properly translate them into in-memory queries.  That doesn't sound like any product I'm aware of, but hopefully someone else will know of one.  Good luck.

Comment: Yes, "not implemented in any datastore". So far the only things I think that can work that way(but using their own query language) are the opensource project: MetaModel that can query POJO's and JOOQ. I was wondering if there was any other ones beside these that can do this. Thanks for your great responses Tim, I really appreciate your input.